# Camel File: Stop route when all files are processed

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have camel route

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
   <route startupOrder="1">
    <from uri="file:D:\Work\eclipse_workspace\dataEngine_GIT_2\src\data" />
      <unmarshal>
        <csv delimiter="|" quoteDisabled="true" />
    </unmarshal>
    <to uri="bean:csvProcessor?method=processNew" />
</route>

</routes>
```

It continuously polls the directory.

I want to stop polling if this job is triggered once.

If all files are processed route should stop

How Can I do this ??

I tried below

```
<from uri="timer:foo?repeatCount=1" />
            <pollEnrich>
                <constant>file:D:\Work\eclipse_workspace\dataEngine_GIT_2\src\data</constant>
            </pollEnrich>
```

But it still polls continuously

Note: I am using spring Camel.

Answer (score 4):

You can subscribe to the [OnCompletion](http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html) callback (which is invoked when the exchange is complete). And you can stop the route using the [Control Bus EIP](http://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html).

Example:

```
<route startupOrder="1" id="myRoute">
    <from uri="file:D:\Work\eclipse_workspace\dataEngine_GIT_2\src\data" />
    <onCompletion>
        <to uri="controlbus:route?routeId=myRoute&amp;action=stop"/>
    </onCompletion>
    <unmarshal>
        <csv delimiter="|" quoteDisabled="true" />
    </unmarshal>
    <to uri="bean:csvProcessor?method=processNew" />
</route>
```

Comment: To avoid any problem during the shutdown, if for example another file is polled, a good practice is to put "async=true" in the controlbus uri options.

Answer (score 0):

`CamelBatchComplete` exchange property can be used to know if the poll is complete, then the route can be stopped using `getContext().stopRoute()`